# Why Relaxation Works for Solving Time Dependent Perturbation Theory Problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, perturbation-theory

I am reading Morrison's Quantum States of Atoms. In  the chapter about perturbation theory with a time dependent Hamiltonian he makes the following assertions. He splits the time dependent Hamiltonian in to a time independent and an "insignificant" time dependent section:

$$ \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}^{(0)} + \mathcal{H}^{(1)}(t) $$

To solve for $|\psi\rangle(t)$, he writes it as a linear sum of the eigenfunctions of $\mathcal{H}^{(0)}$ whose coefficients are time-variant.

$$ |\psi\rangle (t) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j(t) |\psi_j\rangle e^{-i\omega_j t} $$

Where $\omega_j \equiv E_j / \hbar$, and $E_j$ the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{H}^{(0)}$. By replacing this equation in  Schrodinger's equation we get the following set of equations (which seem really long and complicataed) for all values of $q$ starting from $0$ to $\infty$:

$$ a_q(t) = \dfrac{1}{i\hbar} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \int_0^t a_j(t) e^{-i(\omega_j - \omega_q)t} \langle \psi_q | \mathcal{H}^{(1)}|\psi_j\rangle dt + c_q $$

To simplify this, we have expressed the time dependent vector of the coefficients we want to solve for $a_j$ in vector form:

$$ \vec{a}(t) = f(\vec{a})(t)$$

This is the part that confuses me. He essentially tries to make an nth order approximation (second order in the book) by using the following trick. He finds the initial conditions $\vec{a}(0)$ and claims:

$$ \vec{a}(t) \approx \vec{a}(0), \text{First order} $$
$$ \vec{a}(t) \approx f(\vec{a}(0)), \text{Second order} $$
$$ \vec{a}(t) \approx f(f(\vec{a}(0))), \text{Third order} $$

I have used this method before for solving computational physics problems in programming languages, and I believe it is only possible if the eigenvalue associated with $\nabla f$ all satisfy $|\lambda| < 1$, otherwise this relaxation method does not converge to the solution.

My question is why does this work? The function $f$ is really complicated, and so I don't think there is a straightforward way to show $\nabla f$ satisfies this criterion. Why does $\nabla f$ satisfy this property? How can we prove this? Is there an easier way to show this method works or is my assumption incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you solve not original system with infinite sum, but truncated one with $j\le N$ with limited $N$. There are many method of solution of Volterra integral equations, and  the iteration method based on fixed point theorem also is very popular.

Comment: Thanks, I was not familiar with the terminology. But the main question I was asking is how we know the iterative method is applicable to the Volterra integral equations. I will be researching this now that I know the nomenclature.